# Weird Google Places Find Place API parsing fields parameter error with certain fields (not deprecated)

Tags: node.js, google-places-api, fetch-api

I try to run the google places "findplace" from text API. When I run it for the basic parameters, it works. However, when I add on the international phone number and website parameters it no longer works. I am returned the following error:

```
  error_message: "Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'international_phone_number'. ",
  status: 'INVALID_REQUEST'
```

Here is my code:

```
let input = name;
let fields = "name%2cformatted_address%2Cplace_id%2Cbusiness_status%2Cinternational_phone_number%2Cwebsite";
let locationBias = "circle%3A1000%40" + latitude + "%2C" + longitude;

let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?fields=" + fields + "&language=en&input=" + input + "&inputtype=textquery&locationbias=" + locationBias + "&key=" + placesApiKey;

function getData(url) {
    fetch(url, {
    "headers": {
    },
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET"
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
getData(url);
```

Note, that when I cut off the international phone number and website parameters it executes successfully. When I google the property in question, the google place object does contain these two fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so the place search does not return this information. rather you can use Place Search to get a place_id, then use that Place ID to make a Place Details request.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#maps_http_places_findplacefromtext_locationbias-txt